Mock spark.read().format().options().load() but not spark.table()
I have the following function which I need to test -
private HashMap<String, Dataset<Row>> getDataSources(SparkSession spark) {
        HashMap<String, Dataset<Row>> ds = new HashMap<String, Dataset<Row>>();

        Dataset<Row>dimTenant = spark.table(dbName + "." + SparkConstants.DIM_TENANT)
                .select("tenant_key", "tenant_id");

        Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
                mockOptions.put("table", bookValueTable);
                mockOptions.put("zkUrl", zkUrl);


        Dataset<Row> bookValue = spark.read().format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")
                .options(options)
                .load();


        ds.put("dimTenant", dimTenant);
        ds.put("bookValue", bookValue);

        return ds;
    }

In this case, I actually need to execute spark.table but need to mock the output of  spark.read().format(formatParam).options(optionsParam).load() based on formatParam and optionsParam
How can I achieve this?
Initially I started with mocking DataframeReader.class with deep stub (answer) but turns out spark.table itself calls spark.read().table hence spark.table got impacted. Then I tried spying the spark.read() object but since a new object is generated during the call, hence it also didn't work.

"but turns out spark.table itself calls spark.read().table hence" – if it's mocked, it's not calling anything. A Mockito Mock is a lifeless hull that doesn't do anything, unless you tell it to.

@knittl that's correct, that's why spark.table started giving me null. but i want that spark.table should run as it should while the other spark.read.format().options().load() should return what i specify it to, can you help me out here?
two things i have understood is that.. probably spying is the right approach here and we might have to use whenNew of powermockito but i'm not exactly sure how to do it?

You can

provide your own implementation of spark.read().table() (i.e. DataframeReader.table())
check the table-name argument, if the argument is dbName + "." + SparkConstants.DIM_TENANT then call real spark, else return dummy data/null.

See Stubbing with callbacks
